# Jquery how to change class of clicked link

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, hyperlink

Hi i want to know how can i change class of clicked link ?

here is my html:

```
    <div id="category_list" class="list-group">
        <a href="#" data_category="all_apps" class="list-group-item active">
            <span class="badge">2</span>All applications</a>
                <a href="#" data_category="New1" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="badge">1</span>
                        New1
                    </a>          
                <a href="#" data_category="new2" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="badge">1</span>
                        new2
                    </a>          
                <a href="#" data_category="new4" class="list-group-item">
            <span class="badge">1</span>
                        new4
                    </a>          

    </div>
```

and what i want to do is to set class for current selected
`list-group-item active` and for others `list-group-item`

here is my jquery but it isnt working:

```
$("#category_list a").click(function(e) {
    var link = $(this);
    $('#category_list a').each(function(e) {
        if ($(this) == link) {
            alert($(this).text());
            $(this).addClass('list-group-item active').removeClass('list-group-item');
        }
        else {
            $(this).addClass('list-group-item').removeClass('list-group-item active');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`active` is the class you want to add/remove so you simply need to remove it from all links then add it to the clicked one:

```
$("#category_list a").click(function(e) {
   $("#category_list a").removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/infernalbadger/UNMY7/

Comment: It works but links are deactivated. I mean a link doesn't redirect me to the required page. I'm always on the home page. Links stopped working.

Comment: @user2824371 Remove the e.preventDefault(); line.

Comment: It seems that when I load a new page, my code is re-loaded (is reset)  and the home page is still active. Here's what works for me:
I get the name of the page and then the code is executed according to the name of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code as follows:

```
$('#category_list a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings('a').removeClass('active');
});
```

[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/L5f6w/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to exclude clicked link from selectors

```
$("#category_list a").click(function(e) {
    $("#category_list a")
        .not(this) //Exclude current element
        .removeClass('active');

    //Add class with clicked link
    $(this).addClass('active');

    e.preventDefault();
});
```